# Worker pool running tasks of the same kind serially

Tags: multithreading, c++11, queue

I would like to run tasks in parallel. At this time, I am using a very simple
worker pool using a single concurrent queue shared by all the threads.

Every task has a non unique "tag" (an integer in my case).
I would like tasks having the same tag not to run in parallel.

At this time, I have implemented it by having a `Runner` object for each
tag. New tasks are sent to the `Runner` associated with the task tag.

The `Runner` then enqueue the task into an internal queue and the checks
if it is already scheduled into the worker pool. If not, it schedules
itself into the pool.

When run inside the pool, it will pop a task from its internal queue,
run it and if the queue is not empty, reschedule itself.

Most operations (push, pop, already running check using a simple
boolean and queue is not empty check) are "protected" using a mutex
for each `Runner` instance.

My solution seems to be working on a few simple cases, but I fear it
is somewhat fragile (for example, I'm almost certain that there is a
race condition in the "queue is not empty" check) and uses a lot of
locks (one for the main queue and for each tag).

Is there a cleaner solution, maybe less race condition-prone?

Here is a sample code illustrating my implementation (it is probably not working, as I'm replying from home, but I hope it is enough to get the idea):

```cpp
class Task {
public:
        Task(int tag) : tag_(tag) {};
        void run() {
                // do something
        }

        int getTag() { return tag_; }

private:
        int tag_;
};

class Runner;

class WorkerPool {
public:
        void scheduleRunner(Runner *runner);
};

class TaskQueue {
public:
        void push(std::shared_ptr<Task> task);
        std::shared_ptr<Task> pop();
        bool isEmpty();
};

class Runner {
public:
    Runner(WorkerPool& pool) : pool_(pool) {};

    // schedule execution of the task.
    // called by producers
    void scheduleTask(std::shared_ptr<Task> task) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lock_);
        queue_.push(std::move(task));
        if (!running_) {
            pool_.scheduleRunner(this);
            running_ = true;
        }
    }

    // run the task from the pool
    void runTaskFromPool() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lock_);
        std::shared_ptr<Task> task = queue_.pop();
        // we can't leave it locked because the task may need
        // to enqueue another element
        lock.unlock();
        task->run();
        lock.lock();
        if (queue_.isEmpty())
            running_ = false;
        else
            pool_.scheduleRunner(this);
    }

private:
    WorkerPool& pool_;
    TaskQueue queue_;
    std::mutex lock_;
    bool running_;
};

class Dispatcher {
public:
    Dispatcher(WorkerPool& pool) : pool_(pool) {};

    void scheduleTask(std::shared_ptr<Task> task) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lock_);
        createRunnerIfNotExists_(task->getTag());
        runners_[task->getTag()]->scheduleTask(std::move(task));
    }

private:
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Runner>> runners_;
        WorkerPool& pool_;
    std::mutex lock_;
};
```

Comment: What language/platform are you currently using?  Some platforms have mechanisms already built-in to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: I'm using C++11.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15752659

Comment: I think my question was not clear enough: the main problem isn't the worker pool, it is to handle the "dependency" between the tasks: if two tasks are of the same kind (ie. same tag), they must not run at the same time.
However, maybe I should use `std::async` or one the thread pool libraries you linked but AFAICT none of those will "directly" solve the dependencies problem.

Comment: @WillieTaylor Showing a more concise example of your code and tagging the question with the actual language used would be helpful to receive better answers here.

Comment: If you have a small number of tags, just map each tag value to a particular thread. This will guarantee that items with the same tag are serialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reactive library such as [RxCpp](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxCpp).

Use the `group_by` operator to select on the tag for each piece of work. This gives you a collection of observables. Then perform each observable on its own executor. This process ensures serialization, and handles all the grotty details of pushing work across thread boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

It's broadly fine, I've seen this design before and it works.

The only slight concerns are:

1. you're looking up each Runner twice: first in `createRunnerIfNotExists_` and again immediately afterwards. You're also using the logarithmic-time `std::map`, when it's not at all clear you need the runners to be ordered.

   Using `std::unordered_map` and just `emplace()`ing the runner every time would be faster.
2. this section is not exception-safe:

   ```
       lock.unlock();
       task->run();
       lock.lock();
   ```

   (if the task throws, you never re-acquire the lock and the running_ state ends up wrong).
3. this section is probably inefficient:

   ```
       if (queue_.isEmpty())
           running_ = false;
       else
           pool_.scheduleRunner(this);
   ```

   you have other threads to handle other tags, so there's no need to be fair. Just keep processing this runner's jobs in a loop until the queue is empty, and *then* return to the top-level scheduler.